# backbonejs's get method doesn't work

Tags: backbone.js, get, mode

suppose I have a model:

```
window.PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    default:{
        "device":"ipad",
    "lang":"zh-Hans",
    "page":2,
    "uuid":"3c30e128-ed44-43a7-960a-e937457b8b58"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('lang',this.get('lang'));
        console.log('device',this.get('device'));

    }
})
```

but when I initialize it,

```
window.pageModel = new PageModel();
```

the firebug tell me "`lang`" and "`device`" is `undefined`.

Why this happened? How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using
 `defaults:{}` 
instead of 
`default:{}`
so your code will be

```
defaults:{
        "device":"ipad",
    "lang":"zh-Hans",
    "page":2,
    "uuid":"3c30e128-ed44-43a7-960a-e937457b8b58"
    }
```